# Setting SVG preserveAspectRatio attribute dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

If you have an Angular component that uses svg files by referring to symbols from one packed file:

**svg instance**

```
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#my-symbol"></use>
</svg>
```

**symbols as they appear in the imported file**

```
<symbol id="my-symbol" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <title>my-symbol</title>
  <path class="path1" d=" ... data here ..."></path>
</symbol>
```

in order to get control over scaling behavior, every symbol element should apparently have `preserveAspectRatio="..."` set accordingly.

What if I want to do that dynamically, taking the values for `preserveAspectRatio` from component instance HTML input?

Something like:

**imaginary my-icon template**

```
<my-icon preserveAR="alignMeetOrSlice">
  <svg preserveAspectRatio="{{preserveAR}}">
    <use xlink:href="#my-symbol"></use>
  </svg>
</my-icon>
```

desired render:

```
<svg>
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://somedomain.com/my.svg#my-symbol"></use>
    #shadow-root (user agent)
       <svg id="my-symbol" viewBox="0 0 24 24"> <!-- attribute should go to this svg -->
            ...
        </svg>
</svg>
```

I tried `querySelector('symbol')` on the container - but it returned null results.

Is there a method to get into the shadow root and modify the symbol element?

Comment: There's no such method.

Answer (score -1):

In JS you can use direct assignment for `svg.preserveAspectRatio.baseVal.align`. 
Instead a `preserveAspectRatio="none"` in **HTML** 
you can write `svg.preserveAspectRatio.baseVal.align=1` or `svg.setAttribute('preserveAspectRatio', 'none');` in an **JS** script.

The examples are presented here:

- with [code-generation](https://jsfiddle.net/romleon/pa4Lguog/)
- alternatively with [HTML-injection](https://jsfiddle.net/romleon/8zjzboyn/4/)

and available values for *aspectRatio* can be seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio)

Comment: I discovered today that when paths are in svg, code-generation method fails to honor `setAttribute('preserveAspectRatio','none')` but html-injection does honor it, in all browsers. What the eff?  Here's two pens:
Code-gen: https://codepen.io/willkessler/pen/KGgNOz (fails)
Html-injection: https://codepen.io/willkessler/pen/QZKdGE (works)